# Error when using ORDER BY with TCL/sqlite3 on server

Tags: sqlite, tcl, virtual-machine, sql-order-by

On my virtual server (Win Server 2012R2) I run some TCL progams with sqlite3 database.

All parts of TCL, sqlite, database (~25.000 items) and code are located on one shared folder C:\data that I can also access from my local PC (Win10) as drive S:. Some more programs work in the same manner, they are scheduled to run in the night.

The code, now competed:

```
console show
set auto_path [file join [file dirname [info script]] "../lib"]
package require sqlite3
set datasource "./compdata.db3"
wm withdraw .
sqlite3 db $datasource

db eval {SELECT * FROM master_data;} {
  puts "$x1, $x2, $x3, $x4" ; update
}
db close
puts stderr ">>>Ok<<<"
exit
```

runs perfect locally on the server and started from PC.

Start command on server:

```
call c:\data\tcl858\bin\wish85.exe databasetest.t85
```

Start command on local PC:

```
call s:\tcl858\bin\wish85.exe databasetest.t85
```

If I add ORDER BY it runs only when I start it from PC.

```
db eval {SELECT * FROM master_data ORDER BY x1;} {
  puts "$x1, $x2, $x3, $x4" ; update
}
```

Started on server it gets an error message:

> Unable to open database file while executing "db eval {SELECT * FROM
>   master_data ORDER BY x1;} {   puts "$x1, $x2, $x3, $x4" ; update }".

Comment: Hmm. I'd have expected the database file to already be opened at that point…

Comment: You will have to post a complete example that runs on your PC and your "virtual server" as-is.

Comment: OK, I've completed the example.

Comment: **This is solved**.
I updated TCL from 8.5.8 to 8.6.8 and the error is gone....